# Jquery Grupos de objetos com mesmo id

Tags: jquery

como posso criar um grupo de objetos onde o id_pergunta for igual dentro de um $.each ?

```
Object {id_pergunta: "63", resposta: "não", qtd: "5"}
Object {id_pergunta: "63", resposta: "sim", qtd: "19"}
Object {id_pergunta: "64", resposta: "não", qtd: "19"}
Object {id_pergunta: "65", resposta: "A", qtd: "12"}
Object {id_pergunta: "65", resposta: "B", qtd: "1"}
Object {id_pergunta: "65", resposta: "C", qtd: "2"}
Object {id_pergunta: "65", resposta: "D", qtd: "3"}
Object {id_pergunta: "65", resposta: "E", qtd: "1"}
Object {id_pergunta: "66", resposta: "não", qtd: "11"}
Object {id_pergunta: "66", resposta: "sim", qtd: "8"}
```

Exemplo :
Neste caso os dois id´s são iguais e seriam colocados no mesmo objeto.

```
[{id_pergunta: "63", resposta: "não", qtd: "5"},{id_pergunta: "63", resposta:"sim", qtd: "19"}]
```

Comment: você tem esses valores em que formato? Estão em um array e você quer separar em arrays por pergunta? ou você gostaria de mapear para um objeto diferente? tipo { [id_pergunta] : { [resposta] : [qtd] }, ... } ??

Comment: Ola Israel, esta no formato Json, no caso vou popular graficos em canvas e para cada grupo de id_pergunta será gerado um grafico.

Comment: Beleza carlos.. da uma olhada na resposta que enviei, acredito que sirva para este proposito, já que esta agrupando as perguntas e suas respostas de forma estruturada.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente!! Muito Obrigado Israel!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não entendi o motivo de você querer simplesmente filtrar os objetos por pergunta em arrays diferentes. talvez seja mais proveitoso você mapear pra outra estrutura? Segue um exemplo que mapeia para um json:

```
{
  [nro_pergunta] : {
    [resposta] : [qtd]
  }
}
```

```js
var respostas = [
  {id_pergunta: "63", resposta: "não", qtd: 5},
  {id_pergunta: "63", resposta: "sim", qtd: 19},
  {id_pergunta: "64", resposta: "não", qtd: 19},
  {id_pergunta: "65", resposta: "A", qtd: 12},
  {id_pergunta: "65", resposta: "B", qtd: 1},
  {id_pergunta: "65", resposta: "C", qtd: 2},
  {id_pergunta: "65", resposta: "D", qtd: 3},
  {id_pergunta: "65", resposta: "E", qtd: 1},
  {id_pergunta: "66", resposta: "não", qtd: 11},
  {id_pergunta: "66", resposta: "sim", qtd: 8}
];

var mapByPergunta = {};

respostas.forEach(r => {
  if(!mapByPergunta.hasOwnProperty(r.id_pergunta)) {
    mapByPergunta[r.id_pergunta] = {};
  }
 
  mapByPergunta[r.id_pergunta][r.resposta] = r.qtd;
});

console.log(mapByPergunta);
console.log(mapByPergunta[63]);
```